# Whether this is a linear or constant algorithm and why?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode

Just want to know whether this **algorithm** is **linear** or **constant**? And why? I'm quite confused since the while loop is in the if statement
I have been working on this for 3 days non stop. Please help me guys. Thanks in advance

```
    If (row >= 0 OR row < rowsize)
            If (column >= 0 OR column < columnsize)
                If (head == null)

                    head = newnode

                else

                    while (temp => COI < CUI AND no!= null)

                        if (temp => link == null)

                            no = null

                        else

                            temp = temp => link
                            no = no + 1

                    if (no == 0) 

                        newnode => link = head
                        head = newnode


                    if else (no > 0)

                        while (no1 < no - 1)

                            temp1 = temp1 => link
                            no1 = no1 + 1

                        store => link = temp1 => link
                        temp1 => link = newnode
                        newnode => link = store => link     

                    else

                        temp => link = newnode

            else 
                Display “You have entered an invalid column value”      
        Else
            Display “You have entered an invalid row value”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to insert a new node in a linked list.

The Algorithm has a worst case runtime of `O(n)`, where n = number of nodes in the linked list.

It is true that sometimes the while loop won't be executed but we assess an Algorithm in term of its Worst Case Time Complexity, which over here is definitely `Linear`.

P.S:-

You may want to use `If (row >= 0 AND row < rowsize)` instead of `If (row >= 0 OR row < rowsize)`, since `row = -1` will satisfy the first condition but is probably not valid.

Try to include a description of the algorithm and variables and what they intend to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man and also thanks for the tips didnt realise had a error there.